# search filter with userUserPrincipalName always Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I have set samAccountName: mti and set userPrincipalName=martintig@domena.com. When I use sameAccountName everthing works correct, but with userPrincipal not. I want to have two options in same time, but first i'm trying only with userPricipalName.

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(environmentsVariables.LDAP_DOMAIN, environmentsVariables.LDAP_PROVIDER_URL);
//        provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName={1}))");
        provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
        return provider;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to have two options in same time

LDAP allows boolean operators to try different inputs. For example, you can do:

```java
provider.setSearchFilter("(|" +
    "(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))" +
    "(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName={1}))" +
")");
```

> sameAccountName everthing works correct, but with userPrincipal not

By default, Spring Security will [take the provided username and append the domain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#active-directory) to make the bind principal. So, if the user enter's `mti` as the username, `{0}` (`userPrincipalName1`) will be `mti@domena.com` and `{1}` (`samAccountName`) will be `mti`. This may be the reason that it's not working for `samAccountName`.